# Java Nashorn and ECMAScript 6 for..of : ECMAScript Exception: SyntaxError: Expected ; but found of

Tags: ecmascript-6, java-9, java-10

The `for..of` syntax has been introduced [in ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements).

It's supposed to be [supported since JDK9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8156542) as part of [JEP 292](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/292).

However, when I run OpenJDK 10's `jjs`, I get an exception:

```
jjs> for (var foo of ['bar', 'baz']) { print(foo); }
ECMAScript Exception: SyntaxError: <shell>:1:13 Expected ; but found of
for (var foo of ['bar', 'baz']) { print(foo); }
             ^
```

Answer (score 2):

By default `jjs` supports ECMAScript 5, this can be fixed by running `jjs` with the flag [`--language=es6`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jjs.htm) at least with Java 9.

Comment: Nice example of a self-answer. You could improve this, by adding a link to the documentation (if it exists), or an explanation how you figured this out, in case someone runs into a similar but not identical problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Good idea, done! I wanted to provide in my question the exact versions I was running and went to check jjs' documentation. That's where I found my answer :)